# Задать переменные среды для одного процесса

Tags: linux, eclipse, jvm

Новый Eclipse требует JVM 1.7 и выше. Установлена в системе 1.6. Обновлять Java не хотелось бы: чревато.

Как я могу запустить новый eclipse так, чтобы это не коснулось ничего другого? Думаю, это возможно выполнить каким-то скриптом, но не могу найти решения.

Comment: задать переменные окружения при запуске программы несложно: `$ переменая1=значение1 переменая2=значение2 программа опции параметры`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Скачайте JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) в виде tar.gz архива, распакуйте куда-нибудь в $HOME.
Откройте **eclipse.ini**, там куда вы ставили Eclipse, и добавьте или отредактируйте параметр

```
-vm
/path/to/jre/bin/java
```

[Указывать надо путь к бинарному файлу `java`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Linux_Example).

Хотя не представляю, чем вам может помешать свежая JRE, если ее поставить глобально - просто не делайте дефолтной.

Comment: Спасибо! Волшебно! Всё работает.